# Unable to change Visual Studio Theme

Tags: visual-studio

Few months back, I had changed my Visual Studio theme to Dark theme but now I want to change it back to Light theme. Unfortunately, VS keeps changing it back to dark theme within 5 mins of my action.
Can anyone guide me, how can I change it back to other themes?

I have tried some solutions I read online but it doesn't seem to be working.

Answer (score 0):

Start VS as Admin, then change your ColorTheme and finally restart VS immediatly.

VS will save such Settings only on closing and if there is any problem with an extension or something VS would restore the last saved Settings.